# Unable to get Comments from Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Today I have created one account and made it as sandbox users list now I made a request (https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN) now I am unable to get comment data from instagram api response.[image: Response from API]

I am able to get number of comments count but not able to get the comment data.
Am I missing while making authentication or do we need any particular access permissions required?

Comment: Have you tried the comments endpoint? [HERE](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#get_media_comments)

Comment: @sideroxylon thanks for the timely help buddy now it is wokring fine. But when I tried recenet media url in my question I am getting same time comments may be they have changed this behaviour recently